# An HDMI stick that works on the 5 GHz WLAN network?

Tags: hdmi, wlan

Am looking for an HDMI stick who is working on the 5 GHz WLAN network. Unfortunately when I looked in the specification sheet of some HDMI sticks I could not find  out whether the stick supports WLAN 5 GHz or not.

For example the asus vivostick, on their specification sheet they only write that the stick supports WLAN b/g/n/ac, but they did not write if the sticks supports WLAN 5 GHz: https://www.asus.com/us/Stick-PCs/VivoStick-PC-TS10/specifications/

Or the Intel Compute Stick, on the producers website, they only write, that stick provides WLAN b/g/n, but they did not mention if the sticks supports WLAN 5 GHz: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/compute-stick/compute-stick-product-brief.html

So, could anybody recommend me a HDMI stick with WLAN 5 GHz?

Comment: You need to [read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5.C2.A0GHz_.28802.11a.2Fh.2Fj.2Fn.2Fac.29.5B18.5D)  And also [read this article on 802.11ac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ac)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the 802.11 specs correctly, then the 802.11ac variant uses the 5GHz band exclusively, thus the ASUS device should be what you are looking for.

Take a look at the table on Wikipedia. [IEEE 802.11 protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Protocol)